# MVC 3 online store filter products

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an online store using asp mvc 3 and I am using Razor views. I am new to MVC and I have an issue about filtering products.

My approach was:

1. define public PartialViewResult Filter() and include it in the _Layout.cshtml to be rendered on all pages
2. when user submit the filter form show him the products that match the rules. For this I ahve another action public ActionResult FilterResult(FilterModel model)

Questions:

1. The problem with this approach is that the form do a post and user cannot copy the filter url to send by email. I would like to have the parameters in the url. Is this possible using mvc 3? Or should I use javascript to do the filter redirection?
2. Do you know a better and more elegant approach of the filtering products problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use GET method for your form, and you will have filter parameters in URL.

**Example:**

It is possible with BeginForm helper : FormExtensions.BeginForm Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, FormMethod), for submit to same page, it is :

```
Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the form method to GET instead of POST. Im uncertain if you can do this with the Html.BeginForm() helper, you might need to either dont use the helper or write an extension for it. This should atleast solve your first problem. Unless you have some routing rules which say otherwise.